# Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am trying this code:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $numCol; $x++) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numRows; $i++) {
        $arr.$x[] = $todas[$i][$x]."\n"; //problem here
    }
}

echo $arr0[0];
echo $arr1[0];
...
```

But i get this `warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array`

and the echos do nothing. Why ? and what is the solution ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's what you *think* you want to do. Replace your `//problem here` line with:

```
${'arr' . $x}[] = $todas[$x][$i]."\n";
```

But I would strongly recommend against doing that. Just use your bidimensional array.

Answer (score 5):

I think you meant: `${'arr'.$x}[]` instead of `$arr.$x[]`.

```
 $arr.$x[]
```

Will concatenate the string representation of $arr and $x together so you end up with something like `'Array0'[] = ...` instead of `$arr0[]`

Answer (score 1):

When you write `$arr.$x[]`, it is equal to `$arr[$x][]`

Try replacing your echos by

```
echo $arr[0][0];
echo $arr[1][0];
```